# Combine two models and rendering all records in Node? (MEAN)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

Silly novice question.  For an admin interface in my MEAN app, I want to show all projects by users – combining two models (Users, Projects).  Projects contains an ownerid object ID (populated by project user id).  Below shows currently have it hacked to pass all users and projects to the view, and do the work on the front end. I know this isn't correct and is preferred to be handled within the route, but how?

I had also coded this with a promise to return a good array of project object for each user but passing that to the view isn't rendering.

Any guidance?

```
router.get('/allprojects', isAdmin, function(req, res) {
  User.find(function(err, users) {
    Project.find({}).sort({owner: -1}).exec(function (err, projects) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
      res.render('print_allprojects', {
        title: 'My Admin View',
        projects: projects,
        users: users
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Do you want to `merge`  two models?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you can use `lean()` like this

```
router.get("/allprojects", isAdmin, async function (req, res) {
  try {
    let users = await User.find().lean();
    let projects = await Project.find({}).sort({ owner: -1 }).lean();
    res.render("print_allprojects", {
      title: "My Admin View",
      projects: projects,
      users: users,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
});
```